# Infinispan - CLI : How to authenticate using bin\ispn-cli.bat?

Tags: authentication, jboss, memcached, infinispan

I've created a **Memcached Server over Infinispan**. I could success connecting two remote nodes (different machines) over TCP to the same cluster. Let's consider this :

- nodeA's **IP address[port]** : A1.B1.C1.D1[7800]
- nodeB's **IP address[port]** : A2.B2.C2.D2[7800]

But now, I'm trying to connect to my cluster running first this command line :

```
bin\ispn-cli.bat
```

And then trying in the console in the machine whose IP's address `A1.B1.C1.D1`, these commands :

```
connect A1.B1.C1.D1
connect remoting://A1.B1.C1.D1:7800
```

But, I don't succeed it.

Then I added a new user, using `add-user.bat`:

```
connect remoting://username:cryptedpass@A1.B1.C1.D1:7800
connect remoting://username:cryptedpass@A1.B1.C1.D1:7800/cacheContainerName/cacheName
```

The error I get is :

```
JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection
```

I looked again at my cluster configuration file, and I have the following :

```
<socket-binding name="memcached" port="11211"/>
<socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
```

And so I tried these ones and which failed :

```
connect remoting://username:cryptedpass@A1.B1.C1.D1:11211
connect remoting://username:cryptedpass@A1.B1.C1.D1:11211/cacheContainerName/cacheName

connect remoting://username:cryptedpass@A1.B1.C1.D1:4447
connect remoting://username:cryptedpass@A1.B1.C1.D1:4447/cacheContainerName/cacheName
```

But all of this command lines have failed.. and the error I get is :

```
Operation failed with status WAITING
```

So probable I'm using a wrong port...

Please, I need your help.

Thank you a lot!